# Win32::OLE::Const Microsoft Excel on network drive

Tags: excel, perl, perl-module, perl-data-structures, network-share

I am facing an problem using:

```
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Excel';
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Office .* Object Library';
```

With the above libraries I am able to read Excel sheets and parse the data just fine when having the Excel sheet and the Perl script on a local copy on my harddrive. However, when having the same located on a shared network drive Perl is not able to open the Excel sheet. The Excel application opens and a dialog box appears where an attempt to download the sheet happens.

The code I am using to open the sheet with is the following:

```
my $filename = cwd() . "\\sheet.xls";

$Win32::OLE::Warn = 3;
my $ole = Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application', 'Quit') or die "$!";
$ole->{Visible} = 0;
my $xls = $ole->{Workbooks}->Open($filename);
my $ExcelSheetHandle = $xls->Worksheets(1);
```

The outcome when executing the Perl script is a "Downloading" dialog box with a statement: "Downloading: \\nw_share\sheet.xls" which is the correct path. Eventually the dialog box disappears and Excel reports that the file could not be downloaded.

When moving the script and sheet to my local harddrive it works as intended.